# What does "copy ByteBuffer" stand for in the following snippet?

Tags: java, io, nio

Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) oracle tutorial, it's a bit explaining how to use the random access capabilities in java.
The snippet is the following:

```
String s = "I was here!\n";
byte data[] = s.getBytes();
ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

ByteBuffer copy = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);

try (FileChannel fc = (FileChannel.open(file, READ, WRITE))) {
    // Read the first 12
    // bytes of the file.
    int nread;
    do {
        nread = fc.read(copy);
    } while (nread != -1 && copy.hasRemaining());

    // Write "I was here!" at the beginning of the file.
    fc.position(0);
    while (out.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(out);
    out.rewind();

    // Move to the end of the file.  Copy the first 12 bytes to
    // the end of the file.  Then write "I was here!" again.
    long length = fc.size();
    fc.position(length-1);
    copy.flip();
    while (copy.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(copy);
    while (out.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(out);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.out.println("I/O Exception: " + x);
}
```

I have tested this code with and without the presence of `ByteBuffer copy = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);`and the result is the same in both ways. 
Does anybody see any use in using `ByteBuffer copy = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);` in this snippet?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code won't even compile without that statement.

Comment: "any use in using `ByteBuffer copy = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);` - as opposed to *what*? You have to initialize it somehow...

Comment: Of course I meant without that statement and all those statements who are dependent on it. The object "copy" is obviously to be removed after having removed the constructor statment.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious about that. You should post the code before and after the transformation you describe.

Comment: mm well I do, different point of views :) how cool is democracy:)

Comment: Irrelevant. If you want an answer to your question you will have to make it intelligible to people other than yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of the code test depend on the file you use to test it with. However only if the file is empty should you see the same results with/without using the copy bytebuffer.

ByteBuffer copy = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);

This line simply initialises the ByteBuffer used to temporarily store a copy up to the first 12 bytes of the file contents.

Comment: Actually nothing get copied in that buffer, check it out

Comment: For example, if the input text file contains "The rain in spain falls mainly on the plane" the ByteBuffer copy will contain a copy of the first 12 characters: [84, 104, 101, 32, 114, 97, 105, 110, 32, 105, 110, 32] resulting in the output "I was here!
spain falls mainly on the planThe rain in I was here!"